Issues with useRoute in middleware
When using a composable which uses useRoute inside middleware I receive this warn: '[nuxt] Calling useRoute within middleware may lead to misleading results. Instead, use the (to, from) arguments passed to the middleware to access the new and old routes.'
I tried the solutions from here: https://github.com/nuxt-modules/i18n/issues/2064 and here Nuxt i18n Calling useRoute within middleware may lead to misleading results, but they didn’t work for me. I’m trying to understand whether this is a bug that I should wait to be fixed or if there’s an actual solution. I’m using useRoute inside useStoreAuth(), but not inside checkSession. Since I added useStoreAuth to the middleware, it says I can’t use useRoute. Creating a separate composable for the signIn function where I use useRoute won’t work, because I need to access the signedIn ref from useStoreAuth in both checkSession and signIn functions. Besides, I need to use checkSession within signIn, which means if I create a separate composable called useStoreSession and add it to the middleware, it will also contain useStoreAuth with useRoute.
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, _from) => {
    const { signedIn, checkSession } = useStoreAuth();

    await checkSession();

    if (!signedIn.value && to.path.startsWith('/profile')) {
        return navigateTo(`/sign-in?redirect=${encodeURIComponent(to.path)}`);
    }
    if (signedIn.value && to.path === '/sign-in') {
        return navigateTo('/');
    }
});

The way I use useRoute inside a composable:
export const useStoreAuth = () => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const signIn = async (signInData: SignInData) => {
        const { apiBase } = useRuntimeConfig().public;
        state.pending = true;
        state.error = null;
        state.successMessage = null;

        const res = await fetch(`${apiBase}/signIn`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(signInData),
        });

        try {
            if (res.ok) {
                await checkSession();
                if (state.signedIn) {
                  if (route.query.redirect) {
                      await navigateTo(`${route.query.redirect}`);
                  } else {
                      await navigateTo(`${route.query.redirect}` || '/');
                  }

                  state.successMessage = 'Signed in successfully';
              } else {
                    state.error = 'Error signing in';
                }
            } else if (res.status === 400) {
                state.error = 'Validation error';
            } else {
                const resData = await res.json();
                state.error = resData.message || "User doesn't exist";
            }
        } catch (err) {
            state.error = `An unexpected error occurred ${err.message}`;
        } finally {
            state.pending = false;
        }
    };


    return {
        ...toRefs(state),
        signIn,
    };
};

Looking for a possible solution.

"I’m using useRouter inside useStoreAuth()" - how exactly? The problem is specific to this, consider explaining your case further. Any use of composables inside a store needs extra caution because they commonly have limitations that pinia stores may not have

@EstusFlask I updated the question and shared a signIn function where I use route.query.redirect. I use composables for state management instead of Pinia.

In order to reliably use composables in Pinia store it should be guaranteed to be initialized at the time when they are allowed, i.e. the first useStore() call should happen in component's setup, not earlier. This is not feasible if a store is used in other places such as router hooks, the first navigation can occur in Vue before component instance is created. In case of Nuxt's useRoute the warning explain the problem; even if it's allowed, the value is ambiguous during the navigation.
A more practical approach is to inject a store with composable result at the moment when a composable is accessible, e.g. in root component:
store.route = useRoute()

In this case this is the solution because only checkSession is used in router hook. As long as it doesn't use route, it doesn't matter if the latter is not initialized at this point. This would be a problem if route is used prior to this, and a possible workaround would be to allow a method that uses it (signIn) to optionally accept route object via a parameter. So it could be used as store.signIn(data, to) in router hook, and signIn could use it as (route.value ?? routeArg).query.redirect. Again, not a problem here, but that's how it would be approached if it were.
This also indicates a possible design problem, a store contains routing logic that could belong to a router. In this case sign-in route and router hooks could handle redirect parameter and possible redirects, and root component could react to the changes in store.signedIn state, while the store would be responsible for the logic that isn't tied to specific route implementation.

Thank you for the detailed answer. If I understand correctly, the solution is to pass the route as a parameter to signIn in the calling component or move the navigation logic from the composable to the component to address the design issue. Regarding middleware, when you mentioned "router hooks," I assume you meant middleware as well. I need to check session by sending an API request since the cookie is httpOnly. I can't use useCookie in middleware, because I won't have access to Js. I must call checkSession in the middleware, which sends a request to the server where I use getCookie.

Someone also recommended another solution: to remove the URL parameter in the middleware and instead store it in the state of the store, like desiredPath: ''. Then, I could save the /profile path by setting desiredPath.value = to.path; in the middleware. However, I think this approach would still lead to the design problems you mentioned.

Yes, the answer applies to both nuxt middlewares and non-nuxt router hooks. Do you mean this one https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie ? It's available elsewhere. Any way, that's it, you can use composables in a store but you need to inject them to the store in the right context as soon as they are available, e.g. in nuxt plugin for nuxt composables, until then store.route, etc are null. Yes, you can use a solution you mentioned, it depends if you can benefit from having redirect in a query. I had a case similar to yours because I needed "redirect" to be persisted in url

Oh wow, I thought when having httpOnly: true param, we can't access cookie using useCookie, because we're doing it on the client. The middleware redirects work, but I needed to redirect the user after signing in to the path they initially tried to access when they were unauthorized, or to the home page ('/'). So I will use useRoute directly in the component to navigate the user instead of a composable. If I wouldn't do this, the user would have to reload the page (to activate middleware) to be redirected to the destination or to '/', which is something most websites handle automatically.

And I think I was right about not being able to use useCookie when httpOnly is set to true in the setCookie from h3. I just checked it by logging the signedIn an it is always false, even after signing in. Then I set httpOnly to false and signedIn is set correctly to true after signing in. So instead of useCookie I need to make a request to the server where I check for a session using getCookie and that's why I need to call checkSession in the middleware.

I see, it makes sense. Regarding cookies, you'll naturally have problems with httponly with universal rendering (SSR+CSR), this is what your next question shows. I'd advise against doing this for good design, exactly for the reason you described, you cannot easily determine signin state on client side with httponly. You'd need to constantly rely on backend api responses to determine it instead. If it responds with 403 then signIn is changed to false. And probably have a dedicated endpoint for the purpose of checking auth state (could be getting user profile, for instance)

I see, so you recommend disabling httpOnly in setCookie and instead of making a request to /api/check-session, just use useCookie on client. Then I can also get rid of sign out logic on the server where I use deleteCookie and instead set cookie to null on the client like const cookie = useCookie('auth'); cookie.value = null}? The problem is even when I set httpOnly to false, I can see the same hydration/UI issues. This is the only good video I found on YouTube about auth with httpOnly in Nuxt, but it's too complicated - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5s6SiuJHNk&t=90s.

It makes sense, but there should be specific requirements for httponly and server-side stateful auth to make sense, most times this would be legacy api that requires this. Unless this is the case, there are no practical reasons to deal with this on server side.  Hydration can be real problem, it needs to be investigated further. Can you provide a demo to debug? In the worst case you'd need to put some guards like ClientOnly to avoid this, but it would be good to avoid this as this point this can affect the usefulness of SSR

Hydration stability is a known problem in SSR frameworks, but a solution could be unique to Nuxt. I'd expect that some changes need to be done to the lifecycle, e.g. https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15136#issuecomment-1913669766

I'll try to reproduce. Currently, I'm also trying to move the logic from app/middleware to server/middleware, and redirect and check the cookie there using getCookie and event.context.auth https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-middleware. Works kind of similar - I log in, I can see the sign out button appears, but after reload, signedIn sets to false. However, this time I have no hydration issues..

Here's the repro. Client middleware version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-qn6rvf?file=app%2Fcomposables%2FuseStoreAuth.ts, and server middleware version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-zbl3xy?file=app%2Fcomposables%2FuseStoreAuth.ts. You'll notice different behavior. In the first, buttons break and hydration issues appear after logging in and reload. In the second, signedIn is false after reload but no hydration issues. The code differs in useStoreAuth and server/check-session in both. If you find a solution, could you share it in my next question related to this issue?

Also, for some reason I don't see the cookie in the devtools when I do reproductions on stackblitz, but it's actually there, because the logic works. Probably some stackblitz limitations. Anyways, the issue is reproduced.

Thanks, this helps. I'd expect client ver to be like that stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-afqewc . The logic in a middleware and nuxtReady can be extracted to a function that can be reused between them. There can be some inconsistencies, like abortNavigation is available only in a middleware, but otherwise it's a way to deal with hydration issues in a case like this, or these ones https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13328

Thanks for the reply. I tried signin in/out a couple of times and I can see what you mean by inconsistency - the buttons change when you reload the page, which means the state doesn't persist on inital page load. I think it might make more sense to check if the user is logged in the server middleware when we have httpOnly enabled. Also, maybe use sendRedirect instead of navigateTo. However, I still can't figure out why the signedIn state won't persist here in the second version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-zbl3xy?file=app%2Fcomposables%2FuseStoreAuth.ts.

Can you clarify regarding the persistence? There was  httpOnly: true in both demos. I see user-session cookie value in the storage when it's set to false. Also it runs in a container in stackblitz, so domain name may change. Seems ok when the project is cloned locally

This is what happens if I sign in on stackblitz, but I think you're right it probably happens, because it runs a container - https://www.veed.io/view/f81d7223-4d79-4f93-8ee1-6a040fb51275?panel=share. And here is how it looks if I use the same exact logic in my local project - https://www.veed.io/view/1b097611-ad64-4ece-ae37-4d3679d7652b?panel=share. Some weird things happen: I first log in, then I reload and see no sign out button, then I click on sign in link and the sign out button appears again. By default sign in link leads to another page. When signing out the link starts to work.

The first video is private. Does this happen with the updated demo I posted above?

I updated the video, it shouldn't be private now. Yes, the first video is your demo.

Did the video open?

I didn't notice the last comment. Yes, I see it now. Can you clarify, did you try to clone stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-afqewc locally? I failed to notice inconsistencies with the way sign in/out links are rendered

Thanks for the help! I didn't notice onNuxtReady in app.vue at first, it fixed the issue, but there's still a brief flash when navigating: https://www.veed.io/view/4a2f8c88-cbde-4732-b570-0cc74048e6eb?panel=share. Adding a fade-in to the elements on page reload fixes it, but if the website doesn't have a transition the flash is going to look odd.

The only issue left that I've noticed is if you paste /about directly in the URL instead of using NuxtLink, the page briefly shows as unauthorized before redirecting to /sign-in. Removing if (import.meta.server) return; from the middleware resolves this, but then it redirects to /signin upon reloading the /profile page. Repro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-55ddyx?file=app%2Fmiddleware%2Fauth.global.ts. I removed the modal for convenience.
It’s sad that Nuxt docs don't cover auth with httpOnly and the need for onNuxtReady. I would never guess I need to use it.

Same happens with httpOnly: false.

I'd probably choose some other way that is listed in linked gh issues if possible, but onNuxtReady is ok and gives more control over the situation than routeRules, for instance. Do you mean that "sign in" is shortly shown and then replaced with "sign out" on page load when a user is signed?

Yes, I mean that.

I think I tried the solutions from gh but they didn't work for me. I might try again. onNuxtReady seems ok, except this issue when you paste /about in the URL and the page shows when you are unauthorized (this page should be allowed only to logged in users).

This part is expected and would be the same in any SSR+CSR situation, not specific to Nuxt. It's a trade-off between visual vs actual presentation. If you need "sign in" string to exist in noscript version of the page that is guaranteed to be read by crawlers then leave it as is. If you need it to look neater then render sign in/out link only on client side and render empty space or a loader on server. This is purely cosmetic issue at this point and solved with ClientOnly+fallback.

Only the pages that are available to a guest should be SSRed (this is what routeRules is about), unless you need some placeholder on auth-only pages for SEO purposes, etc . I'd solve this by putting "role" field to route meta in vanilla vue router, and I suppose it's the same with nuxt definePageMeta. Then skip SSR for to.meta.myRole === 'registered'

'Only the pages that are available to a guest should be SSRed' is there anything about it in the docs? I couldn't find about it. That sounds odd, although disabling ssr to /profile in routeRules in nuxt.config.ts solves the issue. Maybe I should use a server middleware that check if there is a session attached to a request and if they're authorized, else redirect early with a 3xx redirect to login https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-middleware. Seems like redirecting using js causes a lot of issues, especially with httpOnly.

Not sure about nuxt docs, it's just common sense, ssr needs to serve a purpose (seo, perf) & it's restricted by the way auth is handled. If it's neither then on user pages it just adds complexity without benefits & you have nothing useful to render on server side. "Maybe I should use a server middleware" - this only makes sense if you have a session available on server side. As I probably mentioned earlier, stateful cookie-based auth is IMO a legacy scenario that needs to be justified. If you want it to be future proof, not a good idea, e.g stateless auth like JWT is orthogonal to this

I fixed it without disabling SSR by handling redirects and checking for a cookie in server/middleware/auth.ts. I think client middleware is still needed since, once loaded, Nuxt becomes a Vue app, all navigation is performed like in a SPA by default.
Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-b6hudi?file=app%2Fcomponents%2FAppHeader.vue
When you authorize and reload on /about, it sometimes redirects to /sign-in for 1 sec and then back. This doesn’t happen locally, again likely due to Stackblitz's service worker, you can try it as well.

"As I probably mentioned earlier, stateful cookie-based auth is IMO a legacy scenario that needs to be justified" I see, I'll take it to the account. So you recommend using JWT instead of sessions. I recently discussed about this with other devs and most of them told me that sessions are more reliable despite JWT being a popular approach, but now I don't even know if that's true.

Checked the demo locally. When reloaded on /about, it redirects to /sign-in and then to /, not /about, likely because of this if (signedIn.value && to.path === '/sign-in') { return navigateTo('/'), doesn't look right.

JWT isn't the holy grail but I'd go with it as a rule of thumb. I'm not sure what could be the concern with reliability. I see no fundamental problems with it if it's used the right way. And it naturally causes less problems than cookies if you ever need to use the same api with non-browser clients. As said, SS auth may have uses but needs to be justified, like improving seo or performance on user pages, I wouldn't call these usual demands for regular SSR app

Thank you for the recommendations!
